# Determining the determinant of a matrix composed by an expression

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-equations

So my problem is this i have a matrix $4\times4$ $G$ which is unknown except for its determinant which is $2^{11}$ and i also have this expression $G^2-36G + 27I = 0$

And what im asked is to calculate the determinant of this $4^{-1}G-9I$ and I know it's $4^{-4}\det(G-9I)$, but the problem is that i got stuck because of that $-$ symbol

So if someone can help me solve this I would appreciate it a lot

Comment: In what way is the matrix $F$ related to your question?

Comment: Also, it is not at all clear what the expression `4^-1G-9I` is supposed to mean

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Please try to use MathJax more consistently (surround mathematical expressions with $s, even in paragraphs)

Comment: Do you need to calculate the determinant of $4^{-1}G-9I$ or of $4^{-1}(G-9I)?$.  Also, you say you're stuck because of the $-$ sign.  Are you referring to the sign in $G-9I$?

Comment: its the determinat of  $4^{-1}G-9I$ and yes its the sign in  $G-9I$

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to factor out the 1/4 from the whole expression.
$\text{det}(4^{-1}G-9I)=2^{-8}\text{det}(G-36I)$  was what you were looking for.

From there, notice that $G^2-36G+27I=G(G-36I)-27I$
so since the left hand side is $0$, we find that
$G(G-36I)=27I$
and
$\text{det}(G)\text{det}(G-36I)=27^4\text{det}(G-I)$
by multiplicativity of the determinant
And so it follows that $\text{det}(4^{-1}G-9I)=2^{-19}*3^{12}$

Comment: Omg man that was it thanks man